# Unable to get bootstrap working for IE8 on custom theme

Tags: theming, bootstrap-theme

I'm attempting to get bootstrap to work for a custom theme. It works fine in everything except for IE8.

The page in question has the following content

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4>
            Content Here
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4>
            Content Here
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4>
            Content Here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I understand that IE8 doesn't understand media queries or @import. So I've used html5shiv and respond.js to resolve this.

At the top of my page in the head tag I've included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://it.med.uky.edu/sites/all/themes/retheme_alpha_0_2/assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.js?nqen2e"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://url.com/sites/all/themes/mytheme/assets/js/respond.min.js?nqen2e"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://url.com/sites/all/themes/mytheme/assets/js/html5shiv.js?nqen2e"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://url.com/sites/all/themes/mytheme/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js?nqen2e"></script>
```

I've also included

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

In the head tag. However I can't seem to get it to be responsive in IE8. It only sets it to the style that col-sm-12 contains and does not properly divide into 3 equal columns at full size like it should. I double checked the size of the browser and the resolution to make sure it is meant to trigger.

I have also turned CSS aggregation on.

Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: Respond.js requires CSS aggregation to be turned on if that helps

Comment: Hmm when I turn on CSS aggregation it makes it so the page turns blank in IE8 whenever I attempt to resize it. Sometimes it's blank as soon as the page loads.

Comment: do you get any console or log errors?

Comment: No but I found it was able to work when I visited the page using https rather than http. I'm kind of stumped